# Twitter Search using POST instead of GET

Tags: actionscript-3, search, twitter, air

Building an AIR search appliance and having a problem getting search requests to work.

I am using application only authentication and am able to correctly obtain my Bearer token

However, no matter what i try my subsequent search requests always return

```
"Invalid or expired token",
```

The AS3 documentations says that custom HTTP request headers are only supported for POST requests, not for GET requests.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html

So, in order to send an Authorization header, I assume I must use POST, but will the twitter search API still work?

Comment: Likely not possible. `POST` and `GET`, by definition, should have very different use cases. It's rare that an API will accept both for the same actions. There are Twitter libraries available, however. Why not use those or look at how they are doing it?

Comment: Of course I am using 3rd party Twitter libraries, but there doesn't seem to be consistency in use of GET vs POST for token requests. hence my question